# NodeRED : chart node does not show multiple lines?

Tags: charts, node-red

I have a NodeRED flow setup with a `chart` node. In my `function` node I have a super simple code as following

```
var left = {payload : msg.payload.readResults[0].v };
var right = {payload : msg.payload.readResults[1].v };


return [[left,right]];
```

Now I have a `debug` node connected to both `function` node and `chart` node and was hoping the cart would output 2 lines(one for each result).

But all I see is just one line with one color and the `debug` node connected to the `graph` is outputting Arrays of multiple objects while the `debug` node connected to the `function` is outputting the numbers as I'm expecting.

What am I doing wrong here to get output of 2 lines(left and right variables) with different colors?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `msg.topic` values to each message so the chart node knows to assign the values to different datasets.

As it is it will just plot both messages as if they are the same dataset.

From the [docs](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/blob/master/Charts.md):

> **Line charts**
>
> To display two or more lines on the same chart then each msg must also
> contain topic property that identifies which data series it belongs to
>
> - for example:
>
>   ```
>   {topic:"temperature", payload:22}
>   {topic:"humidity", payload:66}
>   ```